# Low delay audio on Android via NDK

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk

It seems that this question has been asked before, I just would like to know whether there is an update in Android.

I plan to write an audio application involving low delay audio I/O (appr. < 10 ms). It seems not to be possible based on the methods proposed by the SDK, hence is there - in the meantime - a way to achieve this goal using the NDK?

Answer (score 4):

there are currently no libraries in the NDK for accessing the android sound system, at least none that are considered safe to use (are stable).

Have you done any tests with the AudioTrack class?  Its the lowest latency option available at the moment.

Comment: The problem is the minimum buffersize constraint of the AudioTrack class. This size is significantly too large to realize low delay audio. And on real devices (Motorola Droid), the shown buffersize is even higher than with the emulator..

Comment: @hkhauke The size of the AudioTrack buffer won't impact the latency of audio playback.  To put it another way you don't have to fill the AudioTrack buffer for playback to start if you've set MODE_STREAM.  The real question will be how fast the underlying audio system in Android performs as well as how fast the audio hardware itself is.

Comment: Thank you for that hint, I will test that mode!

Comment: @user332530 Were you able to confirm that you don't need to fill up the buffer before playback? I'm seeing different results.

Comment: @Phonon I believe that they OpenSL portion of the NDK is now stable (as of 2.3) and usable if you need true low latency, there were also improvements to the java side capabilities and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently 2 main apis are exposed in NDK for Audio:
OpenSL (from Android 2.3 Api level 9)
OpenMAX AL (from Android 4.0 Api level 14)

A good start point to learn about the OpenSL API in Android is in the samples code of the NDK:
look at "native-audio" sample.

Measurement about performances were made in this blog:
http://audioprograming.wordpress.com/

As summary the best latencies obtained were around 100-200ms, far from your target.
But, from android NDK documentation, the OpenSL interface is the one that in the future will benefit most from HW acceleration to go towards low latency.